# Update OneToOneField Relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models, model

I want to update to exera field of User models in Django programmatically in my program.
how can i update the extra field of User model in Django?

```
def user_profile(request):
    query_set = str(Group.objects.filter(user=request.user)[0])
    if query_set == 'user':
        user = request.user
        name = user.first_name
        family = user.last_name
        extrainfo = ExtraInfo.objects.get(User=user)
        extrainfo.title = 'business'
        extrainfo.save()
        return render(request, 'user-profile.html', {'name': name, 'family': family, 'title': user.extrainfo.title})
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'Unauthorized Access!')
        return render(request, 'warnings.html')
```

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class ExtraInfo(models.Model):
    User = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
```

Comment: you want to update user's extra info without query extra info manually?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to get or create the extra info since the first time you don´t have the object, try change this line:

```
extrainfo = ExtraInfo.objects.get(User=user)
```

for

```
extrainfo = ExtraInfo.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

and then you can update your response, that's your real error in this line:

```
return render(request, 'user-profile.html', {'name': name, 'family': family, 'title': user.extrainfo.title})
```

you should use the `extrainfo.title` instead `user.extrainfo.title`, since at this time your `user` object is not aware about relation with `extrainfo` instance, for that you need to make a `user.refresh_from_db()`, I suggest to use the `extrainfo` object directly in this scenario

Answer (score -1):

You can do that automatically

```
user.extrainfo = ExtraInfo()
user.extrainfo.title = 'business'
user.extrainfo.save()
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work! I got this error.

RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /user-profile/

User has no extrainfo.